# Contar días de asistencia en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Buenas noches con todos... Me encuentro en un dilema sucede que tengo una base de datos sql server 2012, en la cual se registran las ventas de los asesores comerciales, pero no hay un campo en el que se registre la asistencia de los asesores.

1_ necesito contar los días que han asistido los asesores al trabajo.

2_ con esta información necesito dividir para el número de ventas y sacar un porcentaje.

Paso a ingresar el scrip de sql y ver si me pueden ayudar, de antemano muy agradecido.

```
SELECT operador as ASESOR, COUNT(estado) AS Asistencia
FROM AUSTRO_GESTION 
WHERE fecha >= '01-07-2019' AND fecha <= '31-07-2019' AND estado = 'acepta'
GROUP BY operador
ORDER BY operador
```

Cabe recalcar que la asistencia referenciamos con la venta realizada, es decir, que si el asesor vendió ese día se almacena en la base VENTAS, campo -estado- 'acepta', pero si contamos los 'acepta' nos da igual a las ventas diarias no a la asistencia del asesor a su jornada laboral, entonces deseo una instrucción o algo que me despliegue la información, si asistió 15 días el asesor ese sea el valor que salga, no 70 ni 90 que son las ventas totales del mes. Gracias

Comment: mis ojos x.x! mayúsculas == gritar. Edita tu pregunta con mejor formato por favor. Gracias

Comment: Ok, gracias por tu sugerencia.

Comment: vale, gracias a ti por colaborar con el orden del sitio :D

Comment: Ha de ser unicamente en SQL o puedes hacer query's y usar .net?

Comment: No entiendo, si ya estas diciendo que "no hay un campo en el que se registre la asistencia de los asesores" ¿como esperas obtener dicha información? Creo que debes plantearte primero como registrarlo (creo que otra tabla "Asistencia" es lo mejor)  y despues ya contrastar los datos entre tablas.

Comment: Y si, en lugar de contar el estado, cuentas las fechas, aplicando el filtro de distinct? No se si funcione, pero sería algo así como `SELECT operador as ASESOR, COUNT(DISTINCT(fecha)) AS Asistencia
FROM AUSTRO_GESTION 
WHERE fecha >= '01-07-2019' AND fecha <= '31-07-2019' AND estado = 'acepta'
GROUP BY operador
ORDER BY operador`

Comment: Por favor, comparte la estructura de la tabla con datos de prueba y resultados esperados basados en los datos de prueba. Así tendremos una idea más clara de lo que buscas.

Comment: Gracias a todos por sus respuestas, voy a explicarme un poco mejor.

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras deberías poner tu comentario como respuesta. Creo que es la opción correcta. Solo que DISTINCT no necesita paréntesis.

Comment: Ya la publiqué. Los paréntesis no estorban (hice pruebas aquí primero)

Answer (score 0):

Y si, en lugar de contar el estado, cuentas las fechas, aplicando la opción de distinct? No se si funcione, pero sería algo como

```
SELECT operador as ASESOR, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT fecha) AS Asistencia 
FROM AUSTRO_GESTION 
WHERE fecha >= '01-07-2019' AND fecha <= '31-07-2019' 
AND estado = 'acepta' 
GROUP BY operador 
ORDER BY operador;
```

Comment: Nuevamente gracias a todos, con la sugerencia de Antonio me sigue sumando la cantidad de ventas realizadas, más no el día de asistencia el asesor.

Comment: @luagus77 Creo que algo no copiaste bien, porque en mi base de datos funciona correctamente. ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta con tu código actual? Sin modificaciones

Comment: Ah! Me parece que el detalle está con el group by, cambia `operador` por `fecha` y me comentas si funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día amigo, yo lo hice con un procedimiento de consulta, espero que te sirva, me avisas si o no te funciono:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DiasEmpleados

AS

BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE #TEMPORAR(operador VARCHAR(50), fecha VARCHAR(50))
    
    INSERT INTO #TEMPORAR (operador, fecha)
    SELECT operador, fecha
    FROM AUSTRO_GESTION 
    WHERE fecha >= '01-07-2019' AND fecha <= '31-07-2019' AND estado = 'acepta'
    GROUP BY operador, fecha
    ORDER BY operador 


    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(fecha)) AS DIAS, #TEMPORAR.operador
    FROM #TEMPORAR
    GROUP BY #TEMPORAR.operador

END
```

Comment: Gracais Cristian, pero me sigue sumando la cantidad de ventas, mas no solo el día de asistencia del asesor, si en el día el asesor realiza 8 ventas, en asistencia sería 1 y en ventas 8, pero al hacer ejecutar tu idea me cuenta 7 y no es eso lo que deseo si no que, de ese día sea 1, al día siguiente 2, así hasta llegar al fin de mes que si todo es normal y no faltó el asesor serían 20  el número que se reflejaría del 1 de julio al 31 de julio.